# Haskell - lambda expression

Tags: function, haskell, lambda

I am trying to understand what's useful and how to actually use lambda expression in Haskell.
I don't really understand the advantage of using lambda expression over the convention way of defining functions.
For example, I usually do the following:

```
let add x y = x+y
```

and I can simply call

```
add 5 6
```

and get the result of 11
I know I can also do the following:

```
let add = \x->(\y-> x+y)
```

and get the same result.
But like I mentioned before, I don't understand the purpose of using lambda expression.
Also, I typed the following code (a nameless function?) into the prelude and it gave me an error message.

```
let \x -> (\y->x+y)

parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched backets)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As to the `let \x -> (\y->x+y)` statement - the `let` statement is used to give names to things. In its simplest form, the statement looks like `let name = expression`. And from that point you use `name` each time you want to refer to `expression`. In your example, `\x -> (\y->x+y)` is an expression (a value of function type). So, your whole statement has the form `let expression`, no names bound. It has no point such way. Let expression what?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Many Haskell functions are "higher-order functions", i.e., they expect other functions as parameters. Often, the functions we want to pass to such a higher-order function are used only once in the program, at that particular point. It's simply more convenient then to use a lambda expression than to define a new local function for that purpose.

Here's an example that filters all even numbers that are greater than ten from a given list:

```
ghci> filter (\ x -> even x && x > 10) [1..20]
[12,14,16,18,20]
```

Here's another example that traverses a list and for every element `x` computes the term `x^2 + x`:

```
ghci> map (\ x -> x^2 + x) [1..10]
[2,6,12,20,30,42,56,72,90,110]
```

Comment: Isn't it better for legibility to use a descriptive name and then define it in a `where` later? `filter myCompare [1..20]` or `map myTraverse [1..10]`.