# How to convert this let/where function to a Lambda in Haskell

Tags: haskell

How exactly do I convert this let/where function to a lambda in Haskell?

Let statement form:

```
calc x =    let ad5 x = x + 5
                sqr x = x * x
                dbl x = x * 2
            in
                ad5 . sqr . dbl $ x
```

Where declaration form:

```
calc x = ad5 . sqr . dbl $ x
  where
        ad5 x = x + 5
        sqr x = x * x
        dbl x = x * 2
```

Lambda form? Maybe similar to this example from Get Prog, where the variables are declared first, and then defined at the bottom:

```
sumSqrOrSqrSum4 x y =   (\sumSqr sqrSum ->
                        if sumSqr > sqrSum
                        then sumSqr
                        else sqrSum) (x^2 + y^2) ((x + y)^2)
```

Comment: If you need the lambda for for in-line use, then maybe `(\x -> ((x+5)*(x+5))*2) 4` would result in 162. It's not elegant but is short and may work.

Answer (score 6):

The idea is that this `let` expression:

```
let x = y in z
```

Is exactly the same as this lambda:

```
(\x -> z) y
```

Where `y` is being used as a parameter and hence is bound to `x`.

In your case, this would result in:

```
calc x = (\ad5 sqr dbl -> (ad5 . sqr . dbl $ x))
         (\x -> x + 5)
         (\x -> x * x)
         (\x -> x * 2)
```

Of course, outside of this exercise few people would actually write it this way :)

Comment: Thanks brad!  I actually tried that before, but not with the back-slashes in the following definitions.
Q. In the Get Prog example, how do they get away without the backslashes?

Comment: @bevo009 I guess in Get Prog your `where` does not define functions (i.e., `sumSqr` and `sqrSum` are not functions). Instead, `ad5`, `sqr`, and `dbl` are defined as functions in the `where`, so they become lambdas.

Comment: @chi that makes sense, so variables/values don't need a backslash, but functions do. Cheers!.

Comment: I'll just add this for completeness, a reverse direction version of Brad's answer, using the `&` operator (actually what I started with)

```
import Data.Function
calc x = (\ad5 sqr dbl -> (x & dbl & sqr & ad5))
         (\x -> x + 5)
         (\x -> x * x)
         (\x -> x * 2) 
```

...but for some reason my markup is borked and the code is all messed up, sorry!

Comment: Just for completeness: The “exactly the same” is only true if `y` does not mention `x`, i.e. it is a non-recursive `let`.

Comment: Just for extra completeness, they're also not exactly the same at the type level: the `x` bound by the `let` expression can be polymorphic whereas the `x` bound in the lambda can't: see 12.1 on [this page](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/pitfalls.html).

Comment: @bevo009 The idea with the backslashes is that an expression of the form `(\p q r -> x)` defines an _anonymous function_, or _lambda expression_, taking as parameters `p`, `q` and `r` and returning the value of `x`. So saying `f x = y` is the same as saying `f = \x -> y`. See https://wiki.haskell.org/Anonymous_function and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220439/haskell-lambda-expression for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple and straightforward translation to a lambda would be

```
calc = \x -> (x*2)*(x*2) + 5
```

although obviously you could use basic mathematics to simplify that expression a little bit.

Comment: Thanks for that one-liner version :)
How about the Get Prog example I showed where there are named variables?
I've been stuck on that the last 2 days

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what Get Prog is. I actually misread your final code snippet, but having now seen @bradrn's answer I agree with him, and hope this answers your question? I thought you just wanted `calc` translated into a lambda expression.

Comment: It's all helping me, your example also, thanks mate!