# Continuation Passing Style in Haskell with Binary Tree

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, continuation-passing, cps

I'm just learning CPS and I'm trying to pass the following program to this style

```
mirror Void = Void 
mirror (Node x left right) = Node x (mirror right) (mirror left)
```

From what I understand I have to pass the continuation the base case and in the recursive case build the construction with lambdas. for the case of a sum it would be

```
cpsadd n 0 k = k n
cpsadd n succ(m) k = cpsadd n m (\v -> k succ(v)) 
--where k is the continuation, i.e, the stack.
```

Another example with list

```
mult [] k = k 1
mult (x:xs) k = mult xs (\v -> k (x*v))
```

In that sense I had the idea the first idea

```
mirror Void k = k Void
mirror (Node x l r) k = Node x (\v -> k r v) (\w -> k v r)
```

But immediately I realized that I am building the tree without passing the continuation k.
So I had the second idea

```
mirror Void k = k Void
mirror (Node x l r) k = mirror Node x (\v -> k r v l)
```

Now I do pass the continuation, but when I test it (by hand) I don't get to the base case, so it didn't work either.
And it confuses me that I have to call the recursive function twice and flip them to make the mirror.

Any idea? Thankss!

Comment: `Void` has a very different connotation in Haskell than `Null`, `Nil`, `Empty`, etc. I wouldn't use that as the data constructor for an empty tree.

Comment: (`Void` is typically used as the name of the empty type--one with no values. Don't confuse that with `void` from C or C++, which despite its name, acts as the type with exactly *one* value.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One basic transformation you need to perform often to get to CPS is turning

```
f x y = g (h x) y -- non-CPS
```

into

```
f' x y k = h' x (\r -> g' r y) -- CPS
```

That is, anytime you need to call a function in the middle of an expression, you instead call the CPS version of that function, and give it as continuation a lambda which finishes the expression. So let's start with your definition for `mirror`, and work towards a CPS implementation.

```
mirror Void = Void 
mirror (Node x left right) = Node x (mirror right) (mirror left)
```

I'll write `[e]` to denote that the expression `e` needs to be converted to CPS form, and just `e` if it has already been transformed. First let's add the `k` argument, and wrap the implementations in brackets to indicate they need to be transformed:

```
mirror Void k = [Void]
mirror (Node x left right) k = [Node x (mirror right) (mirror left)]
```

Transforming the Void case is easy: you did that already.

```
mirror Void k = k Void
mirror (Node x left right) k = [Node x (mirror right) (mirror left)]
```

Now we need to address the first recursive call to `mirror right`. We call it immediately, and then give it a lambda (which isn't fully converted yet):

```
mirror Void k = k Void
mirror (Node x left right) k = mirror right r
  where r right' = [Node x right' (mirror left)]
```

Now the body of `r` has a call to `mirror left` that needs to be lifted out:

```
mirror Void k = k Void
mirror (Node x left right) k = mirror right r
  where r right' = mirror left l
          where l left' = [Node x right' left']
```

Now the body of `l` has no recursive calls left, and has exactly the value you wanted to pass to `k` to begin with, so the final transformation is easy: just call `k`.

```
mirror Void k = k Void
mirror (Node x left right) k = mirror right r
  where r right' = mirror left l
          where l left' = k $ Node x right' left'
```

If you like, you can write that with lambdas instead of `where` clauses, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! 
just a question
How do you pass the where expression to lambdas?

Comment: There's nothing special about converting these particular where clauses into a single expression peppered with lambdas. You can look up how to do it, e.g. in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54477343/how-to-convert-this-let-where-function-to-a-lambda-in-haskell, and if you're still stuck then ask a more specific question.